# GA cohort style graph by user domain

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to create a user retention graph that is similar to the cohorts analysis report, but instead of having users based on acquisition date, I want it to be based on domain name accessing the site. Each domain name may have multiple users, and some of those users don't login as often.
similar to this:

[image: Minutes logged in and User Retention]

This will show which domains are logging in as opposed to users, and give the retention rate over time for each given company (domain). I have access to the domain name as a dimension, but unable to view retention by domain.

How would I create a report for user retention by login domain?

In the future I would like to view if domain usage has dropped, and create alerts based on this as well.

Comment: There's no actual question here

Comment: How would I go about creating a chart or report similar to what I posted using google analytics? Is there a way that is built in, or would I have to develop the report externally?

Comment: It may be relevant to mention that in my example "Domain Name" is a custom dimension that equates to the domain someone is accessing from. Ex. "www.example.com".

Comment: Why are you sending "domain name" as a custom dimension?   Google Analytics has the "hostname" dimension pre-defined for that.

Comment: The GA dimension "Hostname" refers to the website they are accessing. Ie. my website. If I am trying to track which customers are visiting my site, I need to view their login (Which I can't do) or the domain of the email that they used, which I have defined as "Domain Name".

Comment: I am trying to track which customers have logged in (can be more than one user per customer), and analyze if customer usage has dropped over time.